# Palico quest explanation

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

What does it mean if there is a star on one of the parts of a Palico quest? I noticed after I beat the monster for that section, there's a Palico standing on the chest. Do I get extra quest rewards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer myself.

From [here](http://game.capcom.co.jp/manual/MH4U/en/page-124.html) :

> Quests with a star (★) mark on them will yield more Scraps than normal quests.